# How can I get values from a range of cells to show up in a message box?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to show the values from O1 until O28 but I am only getting from O1 using the code below.

```
    function TEST() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('O1:O28');
  var value = range.getValue();
  Browser.msgBox(value);
};
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function TEST() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('O1:O28');
  var vs = range.getDisplayValues()[0];
  Browser.msgBox(vs.join(','));
};
```

Comment: Tried this one which will work even without join() method

Comment: This is awesome! I will definitely work with that, thank you! I'm just wondering if there's a way to stack the values in paragraphs? What could go into join()?

Comment: vs.join( '\n' );

Comment: Thank you!!! I tried adding one more \ and it worked! Browser.msgBox(vs.join("\\n"));

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.getValues` instead of `.getValue`.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) for `.getValue`

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) for `.getValues`.